# dojo 1.6 DataGrid cannot display lists?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

In dojo 1.7.2, if I create a data store containing array values, dojox.grid.DataGrid displays them with no problem, separating each item with a coma.

However, in dojo 1.6, it takes only the first element of my array. I have a project where I have to use version 1.6. Is there any workaround for this in that version ?

To illustrate the problem, here are 2 examples :

- On dojo 1.6 : http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/HbFNY/
- On dojo 1.7 : http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/QLm65/

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem comes from ItemFileReadStore rather than from the grid.
I modified my code for 1.6 to use ObjectStore and MemoryStore instead, and it worked.

See http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/HbFNY/16/

Answer (score 0):

this is a flaw and yet it is not.. The construct of your JSON is not quite right as any value is not allowed as array unless it is one of the childAttrs. Due to nature of [1,2,3].toString() that is why your attempts on setting values as arrays are considered valid.

The get/set in an ItemFileReadStore works with its items as such:

```
store._arrayOfAllItems = {
 value1 : { values : [ 'realvalue' ] },
 value2 : { values : [ 'realvalue' ] }
};
```

the getter then says

```
store.get = function(itemById, val) { return itemById[val][0]; } 
   // why only the first arrayslot is pulled from store---/^
```

In your JSON construct, what prohibits you from settings the values as such following?

```
   var data = {
        id: 'id',
        label: 'id',
        items: [
            {
            id: "value1",
            values: "a,b,c"   // permit-able string value
        },
        {
            id: "value2",
            values: "foo"}
        ]
    };
```

If you want multiple values by same key of one ID then you must deliver the data as children and handle them as such, like;

```
    data: {
        id: 'id',
        label: 'id',
        childrenAttrs: [ 'items', 'children'], // << default behavior
        items: [ {
            id: "value1",
            children: [
              { id: "value1_1", values: 'a' },
              { id: "value1_2", values: 'b' },
              { id: "value1_3", values: 'c' }
            ]
        }, {
            id: "value2",
            values: "foo"
        } ]
    }
```

However, only the dojox.grid.TreeGrid will allow using multi-lvl datastores