# How to display JSON data in Dojo DataGrid using JsonRest and ObjectStore if JSON is wrapped in a Array

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am using Dojo 1.6 to render a simple DatGrid. Only problem I faced is similar to [dojo 1.6 DataGrid cannot display lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483844/dojo-1-6-datagrid-cannot-display-lists)
The solution here along with reference from here http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/store_driven_grid/ indeed worked and all but there is still one problem with JSON structure. Following are working and non-working examples. I am getting JSON in format where everything is wrapped in items array. How do I make it work?

**The working json format**

```
[{
    "bolist": ["CHM", "CVO", "PMO"],
    "title": "How do I do",
    "painpoints": ["this", "that", "manay more"],
    "solution": "wondeful"
}, {
    "bolist": ["DGM", "EXE", "CLI"],
    "title": "There we go",
    "painpoints": ["Front", "back", "many other places"],
    "solution": "under review"
}]
```

**The not working json format (And I am getting my json in this format)**

```
{"items":[{
    "bolist": ["CHM", "CVO", "PMO"],
    "title": "How do I do",
    "painpoints": ["this", "that", "manay more"],
    "solution": "wondeful"
}, {
    "bolist": ["DGM", "EXE", "CLI"],
    "title": "There we go",
    "painpoints": ["Front", "back", "many other places"],
    "solution": "under review"
}]}
```

Comment: can't you simply add a step comitting the `stuff.items`?

Comment: Have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226264/using-dojos-dgrid-jsonrest-and-subrows-arrays/13249925#13249925) to _Using Dojo's dgrid, JsonRest and subrows/arrays_.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the json like a javascript object ! So try delivering jsonReturn.items  to the grid. That way the grid gets only the json data you want:

```
[{
    "bolist": ["CHM", "CVO", "PMO"],
    "title": "How do I do",
    "painpoints": ["this", "that", "manay more"],
    "solution": "wondeful"
}, {
    "bolist": ["DGM", "EXE", "CLI"],
    "title": "There we go",
    "painpoints": ["Front", "back", "many other places"],
    "solution": "under review"
}]
```